# How can I move the cursor to the beginning of a UITextField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have seen this question asked many times, but every answer seems to be written in objective c, which I do not know nor do I know how to convert to Swift.

I have a text field where I want a user to input a percentage. 
I have it so that when they start editing the text box, the placeholder text disappears and is replaced with a percentage sign.

I want this percentage sign to always remain at the end of the input. I can't seem to figure out how to move the cursor back to the beginning of the text box to achieve this.

Here's the code for my begin editing action (this includes another text box where the user inputs a dollar amount, but the dollar sign comes first so that's no big deal)

```
    @IBAction func textBoxBeginEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    // Dismiss keyboard if the main view is tapped
    tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "didTapView")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    // If there's placeholder text, remove it and change text color to black
    if (sender.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor()) {
        sender.text = nil
        sender.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    // Force the keyboard to be a number pad
    sender.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    // Set up symbols in text boxes
    if (sender == deductibleTextBox) {
        sender.text = "$"
    }
    if (sender == percentageTextBox) {
        sender.text = "%"

        // This part doesn't do anything... Need a solution
        let desiredPosition = sender.beginningOfDocument
        sender.selectedTextRange = sender.textRangeFromPosition(desiredPosition, toPosition: desiredPosition)

    }
}
```

That last bit was all I got from the internet for help. This app I am creating has been quite the iOS learning curve, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: urs seems correct, but u shouldn't make ibaction for the textfield, do conform the `UITextfieldDelegate`, set your `textfield.delegate = self`, then put these in `textfieldShouldBeginEditting`

Comment: May I suggest something?  Why instead of moving the symbol, add it when the users moves away from the textfield. I am suggesting that because if you want to keep that feature, then you will have to consider what should happen if the user keeps touching the screen in order to select a text and press select all, that will include the symbol and then potentially the user might delete everything including the symbol if he/she presses delete.

Comment: @Tj3n - That was my first attempt, and my textboxes are both their own delegates (I have it so that if the user taps away from the keypad it gets dismissed), but it still doesn't do anything for some reason.

Comment: @JuValencia - You know, that might actually be a good idea. I may just do that instead

Comment: Hmm...it works if i put it in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, but agree that wont work in `textfieldShouldBeginEditting `, maybe it just wont work if u dismiss the textfield before u call the code

Answer (score 1):

```
let newPosition = textView.beginningOfDocument

textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(newPosition, toPosition: newPosition)
```

In this we are getting the beginning of the textview and then setting the selected both to the beginning.